# How to set environment variables for apps on El Capitan

Tags: macos

I'm trying to set some environment variables which programs I launch (e.g. Eclipse) can access.  I tried plist, but that doesn't work, not so much because of plist per se, but launchctl setenv isn't doing what I expect.

Example:

```
$ /bin/launchctl setenv AAA CCC
$ echo $AAA

$
```

Where am I going wrong?

For reference, plist file contents are like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
  <plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>setenv.FLEX_HOME</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/bin/launchctl</string>
    <string>setenv</string>
    <string>FLEX_HOME</string>
    <string>/Users/me/dev/apps/flex</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
  <key>ServiceIPC</key>
  <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: tried something like bash syntax? `KEY=val appname -cliargs`?

Comment: After your `launchctl setenv FOO BAR`, try starting a new Terminal (with `Cmd+N`) and then `echo $FOO`

Comment: Yep, tried that, and that's the odd thing ... the new Terminal doesn't have FOO defined.  I'm really surprised about this.